# Filter that works for certain values

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to filter the `PLAN`

[image]

I enter for example the value `1`

[image]

The filter works ...

However, if enter the value `4`, I have a problem ...

[image]

I retrieve the informations of the place `8` also.

I can't understand what's not working?

Thank you for your help and your time to my problem.

**todo.service.ts file**

```
PLN_PLC = [
    {
      PLACECODE: 26,
      PLACELABEL: "Fundsettle",
      PLN_SVM: [
        {
          SVM: 16111801,
          ISIN: "LU0100749679",
          LABEL: "NEKR FD LIFESTYLE DYNAMICC",
          PLN: [
            {
              CODE: "NEKR01",
              PLAN: 8,
              CANAL: "*",
              AV: "A",
              LIB: "Fonds NEKRenta 8",
              DATEV_EFFECTIVE: "0001-01-01",
              PLAGE: [
                {
                  BORNE: 9999999999999.99,
                  FRAIS_BORDEREAU: 0.00,
                  FRAIS_RETRAIT: 0.00,
                  TYPE_COURTAGE: 1,
                  COURTAGE: 0.00,
                  MIN_COURTAGE: 0.00,
                  TYPE_FRAIS_ETR: 1,
                  FRAIS_ETRANGERS: 2.00,
                  MIN_FRAIS_ETR: 0.00
                },
                {
                  BORNE: 0.00,
                  FRAIS_BORDEREAU: 0.00,
                  FRAIS_RETRAIT: 0.00,
                  TYPE_COURTAGE: 0,
                  COURTAGE: 0.00,
                  MIN_COURTAGE: 0.00,
                  TYPE_FRAIS_ETR: 0,
                  FRAIS_ETRANGERS: 0.00,
                  MIN_FRAIS_ETR: 0.00
                },
                {
                  BORNE: 0.00,
                  FRAIS_BORDEREAU: 0.00,
                  FRAIS_RETRAIT: 0.00,
                  TYPE_COURTAGE: 0,
                  COURTAGE: 0.00,
                  MIN_COURTAGE: 0.00,
                  TYPE_FRAIS_ETR: 0,
                  FRAIS_ETRANGERS: 0.00,
                  MIN_FRAIS_ETR: 0.00
                },
                {
                  BORNE: 0.00,
                  FRAIS_BORDEREAU: 0.00,
                  FRAIS_RETRAIT: 0.00,
                  TYPE_COURTAGE: 0,
                  COURTAGE: 0.00,
                  MIN_COURTAGE: 0.00,
                  TYPE_FRAIS_ETR: 0,
                  FRAIS_ETRANGERS: 0.00,
                  MIN_FRAIS_ETR: 0.00
                },
                {
                  BORNE: 0.00,
                  FRAIS_BORDEREAU: 0.00,
                  FRAIS_RETRAIT: 0.00,
                  TYPE_COURTAGE: 0,
                  COURTAGE: 0.00,
                  MIN_COURTAGE: 0.00,
                  TYPE_FRAIS_ETR: 0,
                  FRAIS_ETRANGERS: 0.00,
                  MIN_FRAIS_ETR: 0.00
                }
              ]
            },
          
          ]
        },
       
       {
          SVM:37906990,
          ISIN:"FR0010149302",
          LABEL:"CARMIGNAC EMERGENT SC",
          PLN:[
             {
                CODE:"NEKR01",
                PLAN:8,
                CANAL:"*",
                AV:"A",
                LIB:"Fonds NEKRenta 8",
                DATEV_EFFECTIVE:"0001-01-01",
                PLAGE:[
                   {
                      BORNE:9999999999999.99,
                      FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                      FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                      TYPE_COURTAGE:1,
                      COURTAGE:0.00,
                      MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                      TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:1,
                      FRAIS_ETRANGERS:2.00,
                      MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                   },
                   {
                      BORNE:0.00,
                      FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                      FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                      TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                      COURTAGE:0.00,
                      MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                      TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                      FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                      MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                   },
                   {
                      BORNE:0.00,
                      FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                      FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                      TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                      COURTAGE:0.00,
                      MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                      TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                      FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                      MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                   },
                   {
                      BORNE:0.00,
                      FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                      FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                      TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                      COURTAGE:0.00,
                      MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                      TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                      FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                      MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                   },
                   {
                      BORNE:0.00,
                      FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                      FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                      TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                      COURTAGE:0.00,
                      MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                      TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                      FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                      MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                   }
                ]
             },
             
          ]
       },
       {
        SVM:135045622,
        ISIN:"FR0010149120",
        LABEL:"CARMIGNAC SECURITE C",
        PLN:[
           {
              CODE:"NEKR01",
              PLAN:4,
              CANAL:"*",
              AV:"A",
              LIB:"Fonds NEKRenta 4",
              DATEV_EFFECTIVE:"0001-01-01",
              PLAGE:[
                 {
                    BORNE:9999999999999.99,
                    FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                    FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                    TYPE_COURTAGE:1,
                    COURTAGE:0.00,
                    MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                    TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:1,
                    FRAIS_ETRANGERS:1.00,
                    MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                 },
                 {
                    BORNE:0.00,
                    FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                    FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                    TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                    COURTAGE:0.00,
                    MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                    TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                    FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                    MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                 },
                 {
                    BORNE:0.00,
                    FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                    FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                    TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                    COURTAGE:0.00,
                    MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                    TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                    FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                    MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                 },
                 {
                    BORNE:0.00,
                    FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                    FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                    TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                    COURTAGE:0.00,
                    MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                    TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                    FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                    MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                 },
                 {
                    BORNE:0.00,
                    FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                    FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                    TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                    COURTAGE:0.00,
                    MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                    TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                    FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                    MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                 }
              ]
           },
           {
              CODE:"NEKR01",
              PLAN:4,
              CANAL:"*",
              AV:"V",
              LIB:"Fonds NEKRenta 4",
              DATEV_EFFECTIVE:"0001-01-01",
              PLAGE:[
                 {
                    BORNE:9999999999999.99,
                    FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                    FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                    TYPE_COURTAGE:1,
                    COURTAGE:0.00,
                    MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                    TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:1,
                    FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                    MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                 },
                 {
                    BORNE:0.00,
                    FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                    FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                    TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                    COURTAGE:0.00,
                    MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                    TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                    FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                    MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                 },
                 {
                    BORNE:0.00,
                    FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                    FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                    TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                    COURTAGE:0.00,
                    MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                    TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                    FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                    MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                 },
                 {
                    BORNE:0.00,
                    FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                    FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                    TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                    COURTAGE:0.00,
                    MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                    TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                    FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                    MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                 },
                 {
                    BORNE:0.00,
                    FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                    FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                    TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                    COURTAGE:0.00,
                    MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                    TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                    FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                    MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                 }
              ]
           }
        ]
     },
       
      ]
    },
    {
      PLACECODE: 1,
      PLACELABEL: "Euronext Brussels",
      PLN_SVM: [
        {
          SVM: 836129993,
          ISIN: "BE0974314461",
          LABEL: "BALTA GROUP",
          PLN: [
            {
              CODE: "NEKR01",
              PLAN: 1,
              CANAL: "*",
              AV: "A",
              LIB: "Fonds NEKRenta 1",
              DATEV_EFFECTIVE: "0001-01-01",
              PLAGE: [
                {
                  BORNE: 9999999999999.99,
                  FRAIS_BORDEREAU: 0.00,
                  FRAIS_RETRAIT: 0.00,
                  TYPE_COURTAGE: 1,
                  COURTAGE: 0.00,
                  MIN_COURTAGE: 0.00,
                  TYPE_FRAIS_ETR: 1,
                  FRAIS_ETRANGERS: 0.25,
                  MIN_FRAIS_ETR: 0.00
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              CODE: "NEKR01",
              PLAN: 1,
              CANAL: "*",
              AV: "V",
              LIB: "Fonds NEKRenta 1",
              DATEV_EFFECTIVE: "0001-01-01",
              PLAGE: [
                {
                  BORNE: 9999999999999.99,
                  FRAIS_BORDEREAU: 0.00,
                  FRAIS_RETRAIT: 0.00,
                  TYPE_COURTAGE: 1,
                  COURTAGE: 0.00,
                  MIN_COURTAGE: 0.00,
                  TYPE_FRAIS_ETR: 1,
                  FRAIS_ETRANGERS: 0.00,
                  MIN_FRAIS_ETR: 0.00
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

**todo.component.ts**

```
export class TodoComponent implements OnInit {
  tarificationTitre: PlnPlcInfo[] = [];

  planFilter: string = '';

  constructor(private todoService: TodoService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tarificationTitre = this.todoService.PLN_PLC;
  }

  filterByPlan() {
    this.tarificationTitre = this.todoService.PLN_PLC.filter(item => {
      return item.PLN_SVM.some(svm => svm.PLN.some(plan => plan.PLAN.toString() === this.planFilter));
    });
  }

}
```

**tarification-titre.response.ts**

```
export interface TarificationTitreResponse {
  PLN_PLC: PlnPlcInfo[];
}

export interface PlnPlcInfo {
  PLACECODE: number;
  PLACELABEL: string;
  PLN_SVM: PlnSvmInfo[];
}

export interface PlnSvmInfo {
  SVM: number;
  ISIN: string;
  LABEL: string;
  PLN: PlnDetail[];
}

export interface PlnDetail {
  CODE: string;
  PLAN: number;
  CANAL: string;
  AV: string;
  LIB: string;
  DATEV_EFFECTIVE: string;
  PLAGE: Plage[];
}

export interface Plage {
  BORNE: number;
  FRAIS_BORDEREAU: number;
  FRAIS_RETRAIT: number;
  TYPE_COURTAGE: number;
  COURTAGE: number;
  MIN_COURTAGE: number;
  TYPE_FRAIS_ETR: number;
  FRAIS_ETRANGERS: number;
  MIN_FRAIS_ETR: number;
}
```

**todo.component.html**

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <h2 class="pt-3 pb-3">HTML Table</h2>

    <div class="row justify-content-center">

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="mb-2 d-flex align-items-center">
                <!-- Plan -->
                <label for="plan" class="mr-2" style="margin-right: 4px;">Plan</label>
                <input type="text" id="plan" name="plan" class="form-control w-60" [(ngModel)]="planFilter" (ngModelChange)="filterByPlan()" placeholder="Filtrer par PLAN">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


    <table class="mb-5">
        <tr>
            <th>Tarif Client 1</th>
            <th>SVM</th>
            <th>ISIN</th>
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th>Place</th>
        </tr>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let plnPlcInfo of tarificationTitre">
            <tr class="text-center">
                <td scope="col" colspan="3"></td>
                <td style="font-weight: 800">{{ plnPlcInfo.PLACELABEL }} ({{ plnPlcInfo.PLACECODE }}) </td>
                <td scope="col" colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let svmInfo of plnPlcInfo.PLN_SVM">
                <tr class="text-center">
                    <td> {{ svmInfo.PLN[0].PLAN }}</td>
                    <td scope="col">{{ svmInfo.SVM }}</td>
                    <td scope="col">{{ svmInfo.ISIN }}</td>
                    <td scope="col">{{ svmInfo.LABEL }}</td>
                    <td scope="col">{{ plnPlcInfo.PLACELABEL }}</td>
                </tr>
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this part of the code:

```
PLN_PLC.filter((item) =>
  item.PLN_SVM.some((svm) =>
    svm.PLN.some((plan) => plan.PLAN.toString() === this.planFilter)
  )
);
```

If there is a `PLN` field that has at least one object that its `PLAN` value is equal to  `planFilter`, `svm.PLN.some` will return `true`, therefore `item.PLN_SVM.some` will return `true`, hence the whole  element in the `PLN_SVM` array will be returned.

Consider the following

```
const PLN_PLC = [
  {
    PLN_SVM: [{ PLN: [{ PLAN: 8 }, { PLAN: 4 }] }]
  },
...
]
```

The result returned by `filterByPlan` will include the first object (`PLN_SVM: [{ PLN: [{ PLAN: 8 }, { PLAN: 4 }] }]`) which includes an inner object that has a `PLAN` field equal to 4 which is not desired.

To fix it you could push the plans you want into an array like this:

```
function filterByPlanNew(array) {
  const result = [];

  array.forEach((item) => {
    item.PLN_SVM.forEach((svm) => {
      svm.PLN.forEach((plan) => {
        if (plan.PLAN === 8) {
          result.push(plan);
        }
      });
    });
  });

  return result;
}
```

Or you may flatten your data, ...

See [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new-https-txw1k6?file=/src/index.js).

**Edit:**

If you want to keep the same data structure that `filterByPlan` returns , see [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new-leftpad-yg21wn?file=/src/index.js).

Answer (score 0):

Filter on PLN_PLC is made when some of the element have a condition true

```js
PLN_PLC.filter(item => item.PLN_SVM.some(svm => svm.PLN.some(plan => plan.PLAN === 8)))
```

Seems that several filter are required

```js
PLN_PLC.filter(item => item.PLN_SVM.some(svm => 
                                svm.PLN.some(plan => plan.PLAN === 8)))
       .at(0) // equivalent to your svmInfo.PLN[0]
       .PLN_SVM.filter(plnSvm => plnSvm.PLN.some(plan => plan.PLAN === 8)
```

The result is as follow :

```json
[
  {
    "SVM": 16111801,
    "ISIN": "LU0100749679",
    "LABEL": "NEKR FD LIFESTYLE DYNAMICC",
    "PLN": [
      {
        "CODE": "NEKR01",
        "PLAN": 8,
        "CANAL": "*",
        "AV": "A",
        "LIB": "Fonds NEKRenta 8",
        "DATEV_EFFECTIVE": "0001-01-01",
        "PLAGE": [
          {
            "BORNE": 9999999999999.99,
            "FRAIS_BORDEREAU": 0,
            "FRAIS_RETRAIT": 0,
            "TYPE_COURTAGE": 1,
            "COURTAGE": 0,
            "MIN_COURTAGE": 0,
            "TYPE_FRAIS_ETR": 1,
            "FRAIS_ETRANGERS": 2,
            "MIN_FRAIS_ETR": 0
          },
          {
            "BORNE": 0,
            "FRAIS_BORDEREAU": 0,
            "FRAIS_RETRAIT": 0,
            "TYPE_COURTAGE": 0,
            "COURTAGE": 0,
            "MIN_COURTAGE": 0,
            "TYPE_FRAIS_ETR": 0,
            "FRAIS_ETRANGERS": 0,
            "MIN_FRAIS_ETR": 0
          },
          {
            "BORNE": 0,
            "FRAIS_BORDEREAU": 0,
            "FRAIS_RETRAIT": 0,
            "TYPE_COURTAGE": 0,
            "COURTAGE": 0,
            "MIN_COURTAGE": 0,
            "TYPE_FRAIS_ETR": 0,
            "FRAIS_ETRANGERS": 0,
            "MIN_FRAIS_ETR": 0
          },
          {
            "BORNE": 0,
            "FRAIS_BORDEREAU": 0,
            "FRAIS_RETRAIT": 0,
            "TYPE_COURTAGE": 0,
            "COURTAGE": 0,
            "MIN_COURTAGE": 0,
            "TYPE_FRAIS_ETR": 0,
            "FRAIS_ETRANGERS": 0,
            "MIN_FRAIS_ETR": 0
          },
          {
            "BORNE": 0,
            "FRAIS_BORDEREAU": 0,
            "FRAIS_RETRAIT": 0,
            "TYPE_COURTAGE": 0,
            "COURTAGE": 0,
            "MIN_COURTAGE": 0,
            "TYPE_FRAIS_ETR": 0,
            "FRAIS_ETRANGERS": 0,
            "MIN_FRAIS_ETR": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "SVM": 37906990,
    "ISIN": "FR0010149302",
    "LABEL": "CARMIGNAC EMERGENT SC",
    "PLN": [
      {
        "CODE": "NEKR01",
        "PLAN": 8,
        "CANAL": "*",
        "AV": "A",
        "LIB": "Fonds NEKRenta 8",
        "DATEV_EFFECTIVE": "0001-01-01",
        "PLAGE": [
          {
            "BORNE": 9999999999999.99,
            "FRAIS_BORDEREAU": 0,
            "FRAIS_RETRAIT": 0,
            "TYPE_COURTAGE": 1,
            "COURTAGE": 0,
            "MIN_COURTAGE": 0,
            "TYPE_FRAIS_ETR": 1,
            "FRAIS_ETRANGERS": 2,
            "MIN_FRAIS_ETR": 0
          },
          {
            "BORNE": 0,
            "FRAIS_BORDEREAU": 0,
            "FRAIS_RETRAIT": 0,
            "TYPE_COURTAGE": 0,
            "COURTAGE": 0,
            "MIN_COURTAGE": 0,
            "TYPE_FRAIS_ETR": 0,
            "FRAIS_ETRANGERS": 0,
            "MIN_FRAIS_ETR": 0
          },
          {
            "BORNE": 0,
            "FRAIS_BORDEREAU": 0,
            "FRAIS_RETRAIT": 0,
            "TYPE_COURTAGE": 0,
            "COURTAGE": 0,
            "MIN_COURTAGE": 0,
            "TYPE_FRAIS_ETR": 0,
            "FRAIS_ETRANGERS": 0,
            "MIN_FRAIS_ETR": 0
          },
          {
            "BORNE": 0,
            "FRAIS_BORDEREAU": 0,
            "FRAIS_RETRAIT": 0,
            "TYPE_COURTAGE": 0,
            "COURTAGE": 0,
            "MIN_COURTAGE": 0,
            "TYPE_FRAIS_ETR": 0,
            "FRAIS_ETRANGERS": 0,
            "MIN_FRAIS_ETR": 0
          },
          {
            "BORNE": 0,
            "FRAIS_BORDEREAU": 0,
            "FRAIS_RETRAIT": 0,
            "TYPE_COURTAGE": 0,
            "COURTAGE": 0,
            "MIN_COURTAGE": 0,
            "TYPE_FRAIS_ETR": 0,
            "FRAIS_ETRANGERS": 0,
            "MIN_FRAIS_ETR": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/eugene_kr/tLk9y2vr/35/

```
  PLN_PLC.map(item => { 
              return item.PLN_SVM
                 .filter(svm => svm.PLN.some(plan => plan.PLAN.toString() === '4'))
             });
```